# Can I put a tuition fee remission on my CV under scholarships?

Tags: cv

My scholarship entails an annual stipend for 3.5 years and a fee remission (its quite significant because the fee is 39,000$ per semester) for 4 years. Should I include the fee remission on my CV as well? If so, should I couple them or state them separately? Citizens receive them as two different scholarships but internationals receive them both under one name. In addition, would you put the total amount or amount/year?

Comment: In general, I wouldn't put scholarships in a CV, but maybe in some corner of the world they are considered significant.

Comment: Why would you put the amount? Name the scholarship, if it's competitive, but other information should not be on your CV.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano 'some corners of the world' like the UK. Until recently getting a scholarship in the UK was relatively rare.

Comment: @JessicaB This kind of differences make it hard to compare CVs of people coming from different countries (another example is that of the awards). By the way, how are PhD students usually supported in the UK?

Comment: Well very few students end up with scholarships in Australia and they're quite competitive for international students. It isn't like the US where grad school automatically means that you're funded. Which is why it makes sense for me to include it. Or do you mean that you don't include scholarships at all? I also wanted to know specifically about how to present it, as one or two.

Comment: You wouldn't put the amount? I've seen CVs where the scholarships and bursaries have listed with amounts when they're significant.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano UK students would usually be advised not to complete a science PhD unless they can get one of the funded positions. Arts students are more likely to self-fund. International students mostly bring funding from their home country in some form.

Answer (score 11):

Ph.D. studies are fully funded in many countries such as the US and Canada. If you receievd a merit-based scholarship/fellowship then you can certainly put it under the "honors/awards" section of your CV. However, if this scholarship was not awarded on a competitive or merit-based basis, and it was merely the standard package received by most Ph.D. students, it probably does not warrant a line in the CV.

(This answer assumes you are talking about Ph.D. studies based on the number of years mentioned in the question)

Comment: Yes it was a merit based scholarship. Especially competitive for international students. So can I put the fee remission as well?

Comment: And yes, I'm talking about a PhD. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: @DivyanganaRakesh In that case I would put its name under "honors/awards" but I would still leave out the amount. I've only seen amount mentioned for grants, and even then, its usually for large amounts rounded down to the nearest million or quarter of a million.